# How do you manage focus and cursor position in maquette js?

Tags: javascript, dom, maquette

I'm working on a small application with maquette js. This library uses a virtual DOM implementation. After some user event that triggers a change in the data store it causes a (partial) rerender including the creation of some new DOM nodes.

How can I make sure that one of the new nodes, which is a contenteditable div, gets the focus once it has been rerendered?

Similarly: how do I retain cursor position in a previously focused element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You canuse the `afterCreate` callback that maquette provides to get the Element once it is created. You can call `.focus()` on it or read/write its `selectionStart`. Good luck!

PS: If you also want the focus to work on iOS, you need to call `projector.renderNow()` during the event that triggers the focus.